# 'Panel' data without unit identifier

Tags: dataset, econometrics

I need help trying to figure out what data-structure I'm dealing with, and what estimation & inference models I can therefore use.

- There are multiple units and periods.
- No unit identifiers, so there's no way to match observations over time to create your traditional panel dataset.
- What's worse, there's a high chance that the same unit is observed in a given time period.
- This creates serial-correlation problems, which would be easy to deal with if I could link observations to units.

Example

- Consider data weekly on grocery store visits. For each visit, I see items bought, total expenditure, and shopper's zip code.
- If people were limited to one visit per week, and the dataset had shopper identifiers (essentially tags, allowing me to track individuals over time), I'd consider that a normal panel dataset.
- If people were limited to one visit a week, but the panel had no ids, I'd consider this closer to a repeated cross-section.
- Multiple weekly visits and individual ids wouldn't fit into what I consider normal panel data, but I've seen this done.

My question is: with multiple visits and no ids, what kind of dataset am I dealing with? Part of the problem is not knowing what to search for in the statistics/econometrics literature.

I would appreciate any pointers, including reference to somewhat technical papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is called a "pseudo-panel" data set.

Look up
[Pseudo Panels and Repeated Cross-Sections](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=869445)

and 
Verbeek, M.: 1996, Pseudo Panel Data. Chapter 11 in: Matyas, L. and Sevestre, P.(eds.): The
Econometrics of Panel Data. A Handbook of the Theory with Applications.

If you have a model, then as an estimation benchmark I would suggest to run also basic pooled OLS (which is an estimator that doesn't really care whether your data are well ordered or not).

Comment: Are you sure about this? As far as I know, pseudo panels are only for repeated cross sections but not for actual panel data where the unit identifier is missing.

Comment: @Andy The OP's data is a data set with multiple observations per period, over many periods, without knowing whether in each period the same cross-sections are observed or not. That the OP may also have two or more observation on some cross-section in the same period, makes matters more complicated -but the place for the OP to begin digging the literature is the pseudo-panel one.